# Linux Mint 19.2 freezes and crashes when playing videos online

Tags: linux-mint, intel-graphics, lightdm, sddm

Can't play any video from the internet, no youtube, dailymotion etc. Tried playing youtube videos through vlc, same result. Sometimes, mint just crashes and reboots and most of the times it gets stuck, looping a bit audio from the video being played, till it reboots itself. Be it firefox or vivaldi, its all the same. Tried disabling shockwave flash on firefox, uninstalling adobe flash from mint, no change.

There is no gpu, just intel stuffs. OpenGL Render is Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop. Does the problem have something to do with the drivers? Any insights?

There is a problem with lightdm. Gets stuck on the mint loading screen if lightdm is set as the display manager. Currently using sddm. does it have anything to do with that?